# assignTimestampsAndWatermarks not work after KeyedStream.process

Tags: apache-flink

`assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` before `keyBy` works:

```java
DataStream<Trip> trips =
        env.addSource(consumer).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Trip>(Time.days(1)) {
            @Override
            public long extractTimestamp(Trip trip) {
                return trip.endTime.getTime();
            }
        });
KeyedStream<Trip, Long> userTrips = trips.keyBy(trip -> trip.userId);
DataStream<FeaturizedTrip> featurizedUserTrips = userTrips.process(new Featurization());
AllWindowedStream<FeaturizedTrip, TimeWindow> windowedUserTrips =
        featurizedUserTrips.timeWindowAll(Time.days(7),
                Time.days(1));
```

But not after `keyBy` and `process`:

```java
DataStream<Trip> trips = env.addSource(consumer);
KeyedStream<Trip, Long> userTrips = trips.keyBy(trip -> trip.userId);
DataStream<FeaturizedTrip> featurizedUserTrips =
        userTrips.process(new Featurization()).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<FeaturizedTrip>(Time.days(1)) {
            @Override
            public long extractTimestamp(FeaturizedTrip trip) {
                return trip.endTime.getTime();
            }
        });
AllWindowedStream<FeaturizedTrip, TimeWindow> windowedUserTrips =
        featurizedUserTrips.timeWindowAll(Time.days(7),
                Time.days(1));
```

Windows are never triggered.

Is it a bug or expected behavior? If the latter where is it documented?

Comment: I'm not sure but -> Everywhere (flink documentation and the book Streaming Systems) suggests when you work with event time, to assign watermarks in the source or as close to the source as possible. The things is, when your data process through the pipeline, each operator works with the assigned watermarks and when you do a keyby you mix the data. 
As a way to debug it -> add `.trigger(new MyTriggerFunction())` after time `windowAll` and get the element and from the context currentWatermark. This way you can see does your watermarks moves in time(do you receive data) or they are stucked.

Comment: Please tell me the result if you decide to try this, I'm wondering is this the cause :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case I have a source which reads files and each instance of it reads a separate file. During the simplest test of sending one file to the dataflow, only one source instance was generating events and the others were idle. So after the watermarks assigner was applied, only one watermark assigner was sending new watermarks and the others weren't or they were sending `Long.MIN_VALUE`, when I used AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks.

After the `keyBy()` operator is applied, the idle streams of events are mixed with the active stream of events. Since the rule for calculating the watermark at any operator is to take the minimum available from each incoming stream, each instance of the next operator in the chain, `process()`, stays at watermark `Long.MIN_VALUE`. Thus it looks like watermarks never progress after applying `keyBy()`.

My solution was to shuffle the events before assigning the watermarks. On the watermarks assigner operator the rule is the opposite – always take and resend the highest calculated watermark. This way we guarantee that all instances of the watermarks assigner are sending out watermarks, even if some source instance is idle:

```
stream.rebalance().assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...);
```

There is one more trap here which you have to avoid. If you decide to declare a source instance as idle, while it is not collecting data:

```
context.markAsTemporarilyIdle();
```

you will find that the watermarks are lost again, even if the above hack with `rebalance()` is in place. This is because `markAsTemporarilyIdle()` sets the corresponding stream to idle and in this part of the code (from Flink 1.7):

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.emitWatermark()
```

the watermark is stopped, because the condition `streamStatusProvider.getStreamStatus().isActive()` is false. So the conclusion is not to use `context.markAsTemporarilyIdle()` in the described situation.